# Generating watchers from a loop (in a directive) doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, active-directory

Basically I'm having a problem where I have a directive that has a variable number of attributes that it watches (based on a certain pattern), and I have to generate watchers based on those attributes (and how many there are). These attributes are additionally tied to ng-models (hence when the attribute value changes, the watchers get fired). The problem is, the only way I know how to dynamically generate watchers is through some type of loop, and it seems that the watchers won't work if I do them through a loop. To confirm that it works when I declare each one, I made this test directive:

```
.directive('customDirective',
     ['$filter', function($filter) {

     var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

     var keys = ['attribute1', 'attribute2']

     // I try to generate the watchers here

     }
 }])
```

So basically, if I use this code, it works:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return scope.$eval(attrs[keys[0]]);}, 
    function() {someFunction();});

scope.$watch(function() {
    return scope.$eval(attrs[keys[1]]);}, 
    function() {someFunction();});
```

But if I use this code, it doesn't.

```
for (var n = 0; n < keys.length; n++) {

    scope.$watch(function() {
        return scope.$eval(attrs[keys[n]]);}, 
        function() {someFunction();});
    }
}
```

This is what the html would look like

```
<input custom-directive
attribute1 = "someNgModel"
attribute2 = "otherNgModel">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What is your intent, because, it seems to me that you are watching all the scope for nothing, maybe you want to `$observe` the attributes values!?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding! The intent would be to fire off an event in the directive whenever ANY of the attributes change (they're linked to ng-models in the controller whose values will change on user input).

As I mentioned earlier, this normally isn't a problem when I know how many attributes I want, but this directive is supposed to be reusable and is able to handle any number of attributes (of course, with the correct format) hence I need to dynamically generate the watchers, it seems.

Comment: Well you can easily make a loop and bind an $observe for each attribute that's inside `attrs` i bet... :)

Comment: $watch is for watching scope variables, $observe is the correct way to watch directive attributes

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It was a pretty big pain to have to change all the attributes from attributex =  "modelx" to attributex = "{{modelx}}" and some other things to get it working properly, but in the end it worked!

If you write up a formal answer I'd be happy to follow up and give you both an accepted answer and an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the attrs and set a observable for each like this:

```
angular.forEach(attr.$attr, function (key, value) {
   attr.$observe(value, function (newValue) {
      if (newValue) {
        console.log('New value for attr.' + value + ':', newValue);
       }
     });
  });
```

If your intent is to watch a group of attributes.